# Width of table header columns in Bootstrap table

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I'm using Bootstrap and have a table with the following structure and style:

```
  <table class="table table-bordered">
      <tr>
          <th>Keyword</th>
          <th>AdWords top</th>
          <th>AdWords right</th>
          <th>AdWords total</th>
          <th>URLs of top AdWords</th>
          <th>URLs of right AdWords</th>
          <th>Non-Adwords results</th>
          <th>Non-Adwords urls</th>
          <th>Total links on page</th>
          <th>Total SERP results</th>
          <th>Cached SERP</th>
      </tr>
      ....
```

However, when I'm printing out my data, it looks really ugly:

[image]

That is why I have several questions:

1. How to make a normal width of a column with a text inside `<th>` elements in order to fit the text inside the cell
2. How to make al the text inside `<th>` aligned by center

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are missing "thead". For bootstrap styles to correctly apply, you need to make sure you're html markup is correct.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Username</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Applied <thead> and <tbody> tags, still the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

In SCSS file add a new custom class:

```
.withoutTransfer{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Then use it in table:

```
  <thead>
    <tr class="withoutTransfer">
      ....
    </tr>
  </thead>
```

Now the table headers looks pretty.

Answer (score 0):

try this

**setting widths for your table cells if you apply the rule 'table-layout: fixed' to the table - this has helped me with a lot of cell-sizing issues when using tables. I would not recommend switching to using just DIVs to arrange your content if it fits the purpose of tables - to display multidimensional data.**

```
`table-layout: fixed; width: 100%`;
```